# Nuestro compromiso de responder a Meta y los Moderadores

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, comunidad, anuncios

<sub>La siguiente publicación es una traducción(espero que mas o menos correcta, editad libremente si véis algo raro) de la [publicación de @JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586/346768) en MSE. He considerado importante traducirla ya que nos afecta directamente</sub>

---

Como Teresa mencionó en [nuestra entrada en el blog de la hoja de ruta del Q1](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/), estamos trabajando para establecer nuestro compromiso de responder en nuestros sitios Meta y a nuestros moderadores, estableciendo una nueva política de compromiso Meta. El objetivo es aumentar la participación del personal en los diversos sitios Meta, en particular el Meta Stack Overflow y Meta Stack Exchange.

Una de las principales áreas en las que tenemos que trabajar es poder responder y gestionar la retroalimentación de la comunidad que necesita la respuesta o acción del personal. Esta publicación define un proceso para hacerlo. También necesitamos averiguar a cuántas de sus preguntas podemos responder de manera realista para poder hacer un compromiso razonable (tanto interna como externamente). A continuación se presenta un calendario para poner a prueba y formular estos objetivos.

**El nuevo proceso de gestión de la retroalimentación de la comunidad:**

El personal y los moderadores añadirán la etiqueta [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) a las meta preguntas que consideren que deben ser abordadas por el personal. Esta etiqueta puede ser usada en cualquier meta-sitio de la red. Las preguntas con esta etiqueta de toda la red se añadirán automáticamente a un sistema de seguimiento interno.

A más tardar el 16 de marzo, el equipo de CM publicará la documentación en MSE para asegurarse de que los moderadores entiendan cuándo usar esta etiqueta y cuándo no debe ser usada. Los usuarios pueden marcar una publicación que crean que debe ser etiquetado [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) y los moderadores o el personal decidirán si se añade la etiqueta.

El equipo de CM apoyará a los mods para que se sientan capacitados para tomar estas decisiones y les dará una retroalimentación útil si etiquetan preguntas que creemos que no cumplen con la guía. Utilizaremos esa información para añadir detalles a la orientación de los moderadores o mostrar a los moderadores dónde pueden encontrar respuestas a estas preguntas.

Los CMs manejarán y mantendrán los asuntos rastreados en un sistema de rastreo interno de la siguiente manera:

- El equipo de CM priorizará las preguntas etiquetadas en MSO (y MSO internacionales), MSE y el Equipo de Moderadores.
- Las preguntas de los metas secundarios (no MSO o MSE) se abordarán según el tiempo lo permita.

En este proceso, el equipo de CM actuará como una especie de [operador de centralita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switchboard_operator), asegurándose de que los problemas escalados se pongan delante del equipo o equipos adecuados internamente. Del mismo modo, el equipo de CM facilitará el flujo de información a la comunidad de dichos equipos.

Los moderadores pueden escalar preguntas sobre las políticas y herramientas específicas de los moderadores al personal del Equipo de Moderación y se manejarán como se describe anteriormente.

**Línea de tiempo:**

- **Desde ahora hasta el 15 de marzo**, el equipo de CM trabajará en el establecimiento del proceso descrito anteriormente y los sistemas internos necesarios para apoyarlo, junto con la definición de los compromisos necesarios de otros equipos.
- **Desde el 16 de marzo hasta el 30 de abril**, pondremos a prueba nuestro proceso: las nuevas preguntas hechas en cualquier meta serán etiquetadas por el personal o los moderadores con la etiqueta [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). Estas preguntas entrarán en un sistema de seguimiento, y el equipo de CM las seleccionará y las dirigirá a los contactos apropiados en la compañía para que obtengan respuestas en la meta.  Los datos serán recogidos sobre la cantidad de apoyo del personal necesario en todos nuestros sitios meta.
- El 15 de mayo, compartiremos los resultados de esta prueba. Basándonos en esta prueba, definiremos los objetivos de cuántos puestos podemos responder, y con qué rapidez podemos hacerlo.
- Los objetivos serán revisados trimestralmente, para mantenerlos optimizados, básicamente para asegurarnos de que estamos estableciendo objetivos realistas y los estamos cumpliendo.

**Comunicación:**

También comenzaremos una pregunta para el seguimiento de nuestra participación mensual. Indicaremos estadísticas y otra información como:

- Cuántos mensajes fueron etiquetados [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) cada mes.
- Qué tipos de preguntas eran (etiquetas mas utilizadas).
- A cuántos respondimos, y cuál fue la media de tiempo de respuesta.
- Cuántas están en proceso.
- Cuántas han sido abandonadas.

Junto con las estadísticas, destacaremos las respuestas del personal que son notables, interesantes o divertidas. Esperamos que el hecho de poder ver esta información de manera regular subrayará nuestro compromiso de comprometernos con el Meta y también llamará la atención sobre algunos de los trabajos que nuestro personal está haciendo para mejorar su experiencia en la Red.

Esto es una prueba tanto para nosotros como para todas las comunidades y moderadores. Si resulta que la cantidad de preguntas que se marcan para la atención de los moderadores en el ámbito de este proceso se vuelve insostenible para los sitios más grandes (como MSO y MSE), trabajaremos con los moderadores para aliviar esa carga de trabajo, y posiblemente ajustar el curso a mitad o después del período de prueba. En ese espíritu, pedimos que no bombardeen a los mods con solicitudes de etiquetado, en particular para el contenido muy antiguo.

Creemos que el proceso que hemos descrito anteriormente es transparente y muestra nuestro compromiso con la comunidad. Si tienen alguna pregunta, por favor háganla en una respuesta y haremos todo lo posible por aclararla. Esperamos estar aquí en MSE y las otras metas más a menudo mientras trabajamos para reconstruir nuestra relación y confianza con vosotros.

---

> **Por favor, no empecéis a marcar las preguntas como candidatas a ser marcadas hasta que empiece la prueba.**